# Interrupting active Thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, interrupt

I'm trying to make **2 Threads**.

Each Thread can interrupt the other one, **the two can't be running at the same time**.

I've tried to use the function Thread.interrupt(), but this not trigger an exception inside the Thread.

*how can I stop a running Thread at any moment? I only found solutions that involve sleeping threads or myths that Thread.Interrupt() trigger an exception, not only a flag.*

```
val toTransparent: Thread = (object : java.lang.Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        try {
            if (toOpaque.isAlive)
                toOpaque.interrupt()
            while (opacity > 0) {
                sleep(1)
                activityForUI.runOnUiThread() {
                    searchBarEmpresa_linearLayout.background.alpha = opacity
                }
                opacity--
            }
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
            return
        }
    }
})

val toOpaque: Thread = (object : Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        try {
            if (toTransparent.isAlive)
                toTransparent.interrupt()
            while (opacity < 255) {
                sleep(1)
                activityForUI.runOnUiThread() {
                    searchBarEmpresa_linearLayout.background.alpha = opacity
                }
                opacity++
            }
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
            return
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: interrupt() does set a flag if there are no low level blocking methods being called. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Thread.Interrupt()` from outside the thread being stopped it's generally not a good approach to deal with threads, because it can possibly catch the Thread in some intermediate state, dealing with system resources.

Better create some variables like `isThread1AllowedToRun` and check for its value:

```
while (isThread1AllowedToRun) {
    ...
    Thread.sleep(20, 0);
}
```